# Where are the power-on jumpers on a mid-2013 MacBook Air logic board?

Tags: power, logicboard

I'm trying to locate the power-on jumpers on the logic board of mid-2013, 13" MacBook Air.  [Similar to this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106853/location-of-power-logic-on-macbook-air-13-a1369-main-logic-board), but for the newer model MacBook Air.

I have disassembled and cleaned all components after I had a liquid spill. Computer seems to be charging ok now; previously was not. I suspect the keyboard is damaged but want to start computer to run a systems check.

Answer (score 2):

They are located just above the airport card.  A small flat head or T7/T8 bit should work for bridging them.

You can see them in [step 17 of iFixits Logic Board replacement guide](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Air+13-Inch+Mid+2013+Logic+Board+Replacement/15388):
[image: Power Pads highlighted along the top edge of the Mac, picture courtesy of iFixit]
*Power Pads highlighted with a red square along the top edge of the Mac, picture courtesy of iFixit*

Something to keep in mind is that a damaged or faulty keyboard could prevent a Mac from starting if the power button is always registering a press. If I were troubleshooting this I would first try to short it using the power pads. If that didn't work after a couple of attempts (the flat ones are more difficult to short) I would disconnect the keyboard's flex connection (to the right of the battery connection) and attempt it again.

Obviously, always use caution when working inside of a Mac that has power supplied to it.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the steer. Unfortunately, no luck. Is it fair to assume that the logic board is toast?

Comment: @Spilled Yeah, typically if it won't power on with the keyboard disconnected and the power pads jumped then it's a component on the logic board.  You might try disconnecting the airport card, speakers, battery and SSD to see if there's any change, but more than likely it's the board itself.

Comment: Is the keyboard connector the one that's the tiny -+ yellow connector next to the battery connector? How do you even deconnect it?

Comment: @kiradotee - That is the connection for the keyboard backlight.  The keyboard connection is the connection directly to the right of it.  Technically it's the trackpad connection, but seeing as how the keyboard connects to the trackpad, disconnecting the trackpad connection at the logic board will also disconnect the keyboard..  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The jumpers are sometimes labeled something like "PWR"

Answer (score 0):

I also have a 13.3 MacBook Air Mid-2013 with liquid damage. I replaced the keyboard and the power button still doesn't work. So here is how I get it to boot up:

1. Disconnect the battery for a few seconds (charger not connected) and then reconnect the battery.
2. Connect the charger and after a second the MacBook will boot up.

I just let it to go to sleep when I'm not using it. I don't let the battery go down so low that it would go to hibernate. But if it does, I can bring it back up using the above steps.

Comment: I tried this but now the mac charger doesn't even show any light when connected. :( It was orange before I reconnected the battery.